# What do "it" and "which" refer to in this complex sentence?

Tags: complex-sentences

> Likewise, President Joe Biden’s administration should aim to
> target NASA’s efforts at the things only it can bring about and for
> which there is not already a market: high-risk scientific research.

This sentence is from [here](https://www.economist.com/leaders/2022/08/28/nasas-newest-rocket-is-a-colossal-waste-of-money).

My questions:

1. What does "it" stand for?
2. What "which" refers to?
3. How can I break it up to several short sentences?
4. Are there any tools to help me understand complex sentences?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Likewise, President Joe Biden’s administration should aim to target NASA’s efforts at the ***things*** *[which]* only ***it*** *[NASA]* can bring about and ***for which*** *[things]* there is not already a market: high-risk scientific research.

1. So President Joe Biden’s administration should use NASA for those things only NASA can do.
2. There are two relatives modifying things: *only it can bring about* is a [*bare relative clause*](https://www.thoughtco.com/zero-relative-pronoun-1692623) (in which the relative pronoun has been omitted). This bare relative modifies *things* and is connected with the second relative *(for which there is not already a market)* by ***and***. This implies that the second relative modifies the same noun and that the referent of the pronoun *which* is ***things***.
3. Breaking it in shorter sentences can make it clearer but repetitive:

> Likewise, President Joe Biden’s administration should aim to target NASA’s efforts at *high-risk scientific research*. Only NASA can bring about *such things/ research*. There is not already a market *for high-risk scientific research*.

I would have said ***not yet*** instead of ***not already*** though.

4. Modern Grammars often analyse the structure of sentences. You this particular question should be asked on [ELU Meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thank you! Another question, how do I know "it" refers to "NASA"? It seems not obvious to me.

Comment: Common sense and context. President Joe Biden’s administration doesn't do high-risk scientific research. NASA does. Plus, the focus of the sentence is on NASA.